# Pattern matching character vectors in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to match the characters between two vectors in two separate dataframes, lets call the dataframes "rentals" and "parcels", which both contain the vector "address" which is a character of the addresses of all rental parcels in a county and the addresses of all parcels in a city. We would like to figure out which addresses in the "parcels" dataframe match an address in the "rentals" dataframe by searching through the vector of addresses in "parcels" for matches with an address in "rentals."

The values in rentals$address look like this:

```
rentals$address <- c("110 SW ARTHUR ST", "1610 NE 66TH AVE", "1420 SE 16TH AVE",...)
```

And the values in parcels$address look like this:

```
parcels$address <- c("635 N MARINE DR, PORTLAND, OR, 97217", "7023 N BANK ST, PORTLAND, OR, 97203", "5410 N CECELIA ST, PORTLAND, OR, 97203",...)
```

There are about 172,000 entries in the "parcels" dataframe and 285 in the "rentals" dataframe. My first solution was to match character values using grepl, which I don't think worked:

```
matches = grepl(rentals$address, parcels$address, fixed = TRUE)
```

This returns FALSE for each entry in parcels$address, but copying and pasting some values of "address" from "rentals" into Excel's CNTRL+F window viewing the "parcels" dataframe, I see a few addresses. So some appear to match.

How would I best be able to find which observation's values in the "address" column of the "rentals" dataframe is a matching character sequence in the "parcels" dataframe?

Comment: Try `grepl(paste(rentals$address, collapse = '|'), parcels$address)` Or another option is `Reduce('|', lapply(rentals$address, function(pat) grepl(pat, parcels$address)))`

Comment: Post a larger set of example addresses and show  the answer desired. Voting to close for lack of specifics in the hope that you will amend the body of the question to improve it so I can reverse my close vote.

Comment: Have a look at `fuzzyjoin` package.

Answer (score -1):

Are the addresses all exact matches?  That is, no variations in spacing, capitalization, apartment number? If so, you might be able to use the dplyr function left_join to create a new df, using the address as the key, like so

```
    library(dplyr)

    df_compare <- df_rentals %>% 
      left_join(df_parcels, by = "address")
```

additionally, if you have columns along the lines of df_rentals$rentals = yes and df_parcels$parcels = yes, you can filter the resulting new dataframe

```
   df_both <- filter(df_compare, rentals == "yes", parcels == "yes")
```

Comment: Downvote reasoning: It's pretty likely to fail given the scanty example. It really a regex matching question so look at ... https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285733/should-give-me-a-regex-that-does-x-questions-be-closed (There's additional reason;  I think the questioner should instead have been asked in a comment for code that creates data objects with real-life examples (probably with non-exact matches, since it seems unrealistic to assume exact matches in such cases.)